CSS mapping issue - adding class specificity did not work
I have a button which I was trying to change its background-color, but it kept overrode by the styling from _ranking.scss as told by the browser dev tool and was not because of inherited from other divs.
body #static-page-container .advertise-contact a {
  background-color: #051e4b; // dev tool showed this could not be changed
  color: #fff;
}

When I looked into _ranking.scss
there's no background-color: #051e4b
or the .advertise-contact class.
Is there anyway I can change its styling without using !important?
Things I tried:

Adding id to the button
Adding a wrapper div to increase class specificity

Currently, I used inline style to change the button's background to #000.

Use the same selector body #static-page-container .advertise-contact a and add your background-color and the load order of these styles shall be after the old stylesheet has loaded.
